# Details screen Data not changes when notification tapped in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications, android-pendingintent

I was creating a simple notification app with Alarm Manager. The alarm manager trigger for 1 minute and it should give a notification. but when I tapped on the notification moves to details screen with first content.

It not changing.

Below broadcast receiver calls each 1 minute.
notification changing with different data but not in details screen. that is the problem.

**AlarmReceiver**

```
class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver()
{

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?)
    {
        var dbHelper = context?.let { DbHelper(it) }
        val question = dbHelper?.getQuestion((0..1280).random())



        val i = Intent(context, SecondActivity::class.java)
        i.putExtra("LAW", question)
        i!!.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK

        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, i, 0)

        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context!!, "foxandroid")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .setContentTitle("${question!!.type}  ${question!!.code}  ${question!!.subcode}  ${question!!.shortDesc}")
            .setContentText("${question!!.fullDesc}")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

        val notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)

        notificationManager.notify(123, builder.build())


    }
}
```

Below class shows the notification data in detail.
**Second Activity**

```
class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)


        val law = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 33) {
            intent.getSerializableExtra("LAW", Question::class.java)
        } else {
            intent.getSerializableExtra("LAW") as  Question



        }// as? Question

        Log.e("law:",  "${law!!.shortDesc}")

        if (law != null) {
            textTitle.text = "${law.type}  ${law.code}  ${law.subcode}  ${law.shortDesc}"

        }

        if (law != null) {
            textContent.text = law.fullDesc
        }


        button.setOnClickListener {

            val intent= Intent(this,WebActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("LAW", "${law?.type}  ${law?.code}  ${law?.subcode}")
            startActivity(intent)


        }




    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use [Activity#onNewIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/activity/ComponentActivity?hl=en#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent))，

Your `Activity` was already created, when you start activity again，the `Activity` may be not run `onCreate` lifecycle function, and run `onNewIntent`. OnNewIntent somelike onCreate, they are lifecycle function.

You just try log extra bundle in `Intent` at OnNewIntent, and you will know.

Comment: i don't get it. how to use it with my example. what's the use of this with my problem?